# Is there a command to just run any script?

Tags: command-line

I'm working with multiple scripts at a time, all in diferent languages and I'm tired of typing `python3 main.py` for python scripts and `sh main.sh` for shell

Not even mentioning c.

Basically something like this.

```
run main.py
run main.sh
run main.c
```

Comment: Add an appropriate [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the beginning, make the script executable, and start it by just entering the name of the file as a command.

Comment: i still have to do all the compling thing for c but is worth knowing that i can do that

Comment: The practice of using `sh main.sh` to run shell scripts really needs to die...

Comment: @Jos That's an answer. Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a file something like `run.sh`.
Open with text editor and place your command to run this files in terminal like below example:

```
python main.py
gcc main.c
./main.sh
```

Depending on which source file to compile and run place the code in that run file.
Then open properties and check for executable permissions. You can do this using terminal by this command

```
sudo chmod +rwx run file
```

Then open terminal and execute the run file as

```
./run file name
```

Commands in run file will be executed sequentially.

Comment: yes... but i could have a lot of files or create one just to test something...
in that case i would be doing more work... thank you anyway

Comment: Then create another c or python program which creates run.sh file based on the run command of each files.

Comment: Read the file name. If it has extension .c then write gcc file name.c to the run file. same way for c++ python other src files.